# Characteristic polynomial vs. auxiliary polynomial

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, polynomials, characteristic-functions

What is the difference between a **characteristic polynomial** and an **auxiliary polynomial**?

In our linear algebra textbook: the **auxiliary polynomial** associated with a differential equation is $p(t)=t^n+a_{n-1}t^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1t+a_0$.

In our analysis lecture notes: the **characteristic polynomial** of a differential equation is $p(T)=T^n+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1T+a_0\in\mathbb{R}[T]$.

However, on Wikipedia they have separate articles and are (if I have understood correctly) not directly connected.

Comment: A matrix (linear transformation) has a characteristic polynomial, but no "auxiliary polynomial".  A linear differential equation has an auxiliary polynomial, but no "characteristic polynomial".  The two are related, but certainly distinct.

Comment: The two are certainly the same. The most common name is the second.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom connected as in they are both polynomials of $n$th degree or how are they related?

Comment: Related in that the auxiliary polynomial is the characteristic polynomial of a certain matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in my comment, the two ideas are distinct, but related.  Here's how they're related: we can write an arbitrary $n$th order linear ODE as a system of $n$ first-order ODE's as follows: if the ODE is given by
$$
y^{(n)} + a_{n-1}y^{(n-1)} + \cdots + a_0 y = 0
$$
where $y$ is a function of $t$, then we can define
$$
x_i = y^{(i-1)} \quad i=1,\dots,n
$$
If we take $x = (x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n})^T$, then we have
$
\frac {dx}{dt} = Ax
$
where
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1&0&0&\cdots\\
0&0&1&0&\cdots\\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \ddots\\
0&0&\cdots&0&1\\
-a_0&-a_1&-a_2&\cdots&-a_{n-1}}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is also the auxiliary polynomial of the ODE.